# Как изменить ip через proxy сервер в python

Tags: python, proxy

С помощью какой библиотеки python можно менять ip при выполнении запроса через http протокол, используя proxy сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) предоставляет возможность делать запросы через proxy.

```
import requests

proxies = {
  'http': 'http://10.10.1.10:3128',
  'https': 'http://10.10.1.10:1080',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```