# Замена ip пользователя на другой для доступа на заблокированный ресурс без его вмешательства

Tags: прокси, проксирование

Речь идёт об игровом сервере minecraft  в котором есть ip и порт.
Есть сервер с ip:A, есть пользователь с ip:В. Но на сервере все ip "B" в блоке.
Могу ли я не имея доступ к серверу и пользователю соединить их через свой ip:C?
Что бы пользователь вводил мой ip:C и играл на сервере. В тоже время сервер видел его как тоже ip:C.
Выходит это как Впн, только что бы пользователь не устанавливал у себя программ и т.д, а просто мой ip:port ввел и играл себе спокойно, через мой интернет на сервере, который в свою очередь будет видеть мой ip.
Если есть решение, прошу не кидать тапками и написать как для чайника.

Comment: Вы [Прокси](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) изобрести хотите?)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946412/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-ip-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-proxy-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-python

Comment: Зачем изобретать? Информация что это "прокси" ничего не дала. Это и так ясно было. По итогу информации все так же нет.